# Connections: Exponential Map

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a smooth manifold.

Suppose it has an (affine) connection.

How is the exponential map constructed?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you are trying for here?

Comment: Yes the point is that I don't know to much yet but need a quick sketchy construction

Comment: In order to define an exponential map, you need either a Riemannian metric or a Lie group structure.

Comment: hmm and how does that work then ...is it matter of having some sort of connection (affine)?

Comment: Yes, a connection in the tangent bundle would also give you an exponential map. But not a connection in an arbitrary vector bundle.

Comment: You have to ask a more focused question. Which textbook are you using? Pretty much any textbook on Riemannian geometry will explain construction of exponential maps and existence of normal balls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual construction of the exponential map in Riemannian geometry works also for a  general  affine connection, even if it does not come from any metric, as follows.

Let $\nabla$ be an affine connection  on some manifold $M$, ie a connection on the tangent bundle of $M$.

A parametrized curve in $M$ is called a geodesic if its tangent is parallel with respect to  $\nabla$. The equation for a geodesic, written in coordinates, is a 2nd order ODE, hence   given any initial point $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, there exists a unique geodesic $\gamma (t),$ defined for some open interval around $t=0$, such that $\gamma(0)=p$, $\gamma'(0)=v$. Define  $exp(v)=\gamma(1)$ (if $\gamma(t)$ is defined for $t=1$). Then $exp$ maps some open neighborhood of the origin in $T_pM$ to $M$.

For a connection on an arbitrary vector bundle on $M$ I do not know of a definition of an exponential map (and I doubt there is).